# My project is working completly , but when I changed android studio to another version I had this problem, I have tried alot of ways but it doesnt wo

Tags: android

My app is working but when I  installed another android studio, there is problem now

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Shamel'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download manifest-merger-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/27.1.1/manifest-merger-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/27.1.1/manifest-merger-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake
> Could not download lint-gradle-api-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/27.1.1/lint-gradle-api-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/27.1.1/lint-gradle-api-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake
> Could not download lint-model-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:27.1.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/27.1.1/lint-model-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/27.1.1/lint-model-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake
> Could not download sdk-common-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/27.1.1/sdk-common-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/27.1.1/sdk-common-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake
> Could not download aapt2-proto-4.1.1-6503028.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.1.1-6503028)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/4.1.1-6503028/aapt2-proto-4.1.1-6503028.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/4.1.1-6503028/aapt2-proto-4.1.1-6503028.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake
> Could not download crash-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:27.1.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/27.1.1/crash-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/27.1.1/crash-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake
> Could not download databinding-compiler-common-4.1.1.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/4.1.1/databinding-compiler-common-4.1.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/4.1.1/databinding-compiler-common-4.1.1.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake
> Could not download zipflinger-4.1.1.jar (com.android:zipflinger:4.1.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/4.1.1/zipflinger-4.1.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/4.1.1/zipflinger-4.1.1.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake
> Could not download sdklib-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/27.1.1/sdklib-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/27.1.1/sdklib-27.1.1.jar'.
> > Remote host closed connection during handshake

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Shamel'.
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$600(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:51)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:104)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:180)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:271)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:265)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:226)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
  at
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 1m 5s

---

Comment: Try cleaning and Rebuilding . Also check if you have internet connection on the pc.

Comment: i can not
it doesnt work

Comment: Update your gradle, or re-install it

Comment: i have new error

org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.application']

Answer (score 0):

I have new error

org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.application']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).